# PHP Regex extract numbers inside brackets

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently building a chat system with reply function.

How can I match the numbers inside the '@' symbol and brackets, example: @[123456789]

This one works in JavaScript

```
/@\[(0-9_)+\]/g
```

But it doesn't work in PHP as it cannot recognize the */g* modifier. So I tried this:

```
/\@\[[^0-9]\]/
```

I have the following example code:

```
$example_message = 'Hi @[123456789] :)';

$msg = preg_replace('/\@\[[^0-9]\]/', '$1', $example_message);
```

But it doesn't work, it won't capture those numbers inside @[ ]. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Your problem is the `^` in your character class looks for the *negative* (so `[^0-9]` looks for anything but a digit).  Real answer incoming....

Comment: Also, your JS regex should really be `/@\[[0-9_]+\]/g` (remove the underscore if there shouldn't be any within the square brackets).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have some core problems in your regex, the main one being the `^` that negates your character class.  So instead of `[^0-9]` matching any digit, it matches anything *but* a digit.  Also, the `g` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) doesn't exist in PHP ([`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) replaces globally and you can use [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to match expressions globally).

You'll want to use a regex like [`/@\[(\d+)\]/`](http://regex101.com/r/nM7zS6) to match (with a group) all of the digits between `@[` and `]`.

To do this globally on a string in PHP, use `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all('/@\[(\d+)\]/', 'Hi @[123456789] :)', $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

However, your code would be cleaner if you didn't rely on a match group `(\d+)`. Instead you can use "lookarounds" like: [`(?<=@\[)\d+(?=\])`](http://regex101.com/r/pF1qO4). Also, if you will only have one digit per string, you should use [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) not `preg_match_all()`.

**Note:** I left the example vague and linked to lots of documentation so you can read/learn better. If you have any questions, please ask. Also, if you want a better explanation on the regular expressions used (specifically the second one with lookarounds), let me know and I'll gladly elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) function in PHP if you’d like to produce the behaviour of the `g` modifier in Javascript. Use the [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) function otherwise.

```
preg_match_all("/@\\[([0-9]+)\\]/", $example_message, $matches);
```

**Explanation:**
`/` opening delimiter
`@` match the at sign
`\\[` match the opening square bracket (metacharacter, so needs to be escaped)
`(` start capturing
`[0-9]` match a digit
`+` match the previous once or more
`)` stop capturing
`\\]` match the closing square bracket (metacharacter, so needs to be escaped)
`/` closing delimiter

Now `$matches[1]` contains all the numbers inside the square brackets.